# Is it possible to disable HTTP Keep-Alive with libcurl?

Tags: c++, c, libcurl

I am implementing HTTP client for third-party private API. This API requires to not use HTTP Keep-Alive. Can `libcurl` disable Keep-Alive? Even when I set `CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE`, it still sends `Connection: Keep-Alive` header and confuses server. It even sends this header if I manually set `Connection: close` header. In such situation `libcurl` sends both `Connection: Keep-Alive` and `Connection: close` HTTP headers.
Does anyone know how to force `libcurl` to never reuse connections and send `Connection: close` header to notify server that it doesn't use connection, or `Connection: Keep-Alive` is hardcoded in `libcurl` and can not be altered?

Comment: I'm guessing asking the third-party to fix their server isn't an option :P

Comment: the keep alive header won't be set explicitly if you're using HTTP 1.1; and CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE does definitely kill the connection (verified with wireshark). You have to make sure to set the value before *every* request, though, which could be the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with [`CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER.html):

```
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(void) {
    CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
    struct curl_slist *list = NULL;
    if(curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com");
        list = curl_slist_append(list, "Connection: close");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, list);
        curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_slist_free_all(list);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
}
```

At least it works on my Linux.

Comment: I don't think he's using the easy API. The easy api doesn't pass any headers by default. … oops, that may be specific to my environment (OSX).

Comment: As I wrote in my first post, it doesn't help (at least on Windows). When I do that, `libcurl` posts 2 `Connection` headers, one is `close` and another one is `Keep-Alive`. I use proxy, BTW, may be `libcurl` behavior with and without proxy is different.